# Is this a effective workout split for a 15 year old 65 kg been going to the gym for about 6 months

Tags: muscle, strength

Eat 2800 calories a day and lots of protein

All 3 sets

Push upper body
Bench press 6-10
Incline dumbbell press 6-10
Chest flys 6-12
Shoulder press 6-12
Later raises cable/dumbbell 6-12
Tricep pull down 6-12
Over head Tricep extension 6-12
Assisted dips 6-12

Finish off with core skipping and variation push ups

Lower body

Barbell squats 6-12
Calf raises 15-20
Goblet squats 8-12
Leg curl 6-12
Hamstring curls 6-12
Leg press 6-12

Finish off with core skipping ropes and variation push ups

Pull day upper body

Cable curls 6-12
Different variation of assisted pull up 6-12
Barbell curls 6-12
Barbell rows 6-12
Flat dumbbell bench press 6-12
Incline bench curls 6-12
Dumbbell Hammer curls 6-12
Dumbbell wrist twists

Finish off with skipping ropes and variations of push-
ups

Repeat previous leg day

Monday-push upper
Tuesday-lower
Wednesday-maybe cardio
Thursday-pull upper
Friday -lower
Saturday -Rest
Sunday -Rest

Comment: The reason that your question is receiving votes to close is that answer that you might receive will amount to conjecture or opinion. After six months of training, anything you do to challenge yourself will be effective. (Really!) If it is challenging, it is going to stimulate an adaptive response; if it is not, it will not. Provided you do not over-train, which is the greatest threat here, the primary concern is what motivates you.